# Animating CSS gradient works only if text doesn't wrap

Tags: html, css, animation, gradient

[This](https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/animating-css-gradients-using-only-css-d2fd7671e759) example of animating a gradient in purely CSS works great *when the text or thing doesn't wrap like text does at the end of a line*. But when wrapping occurs, the gradient breaks and doesn't animate. Here is a slightly modified example to demonstrate. Shrink the screen so you can see the second block of text wrap around the edge, hover over it, and notice it won't animate.

```css
.button {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
  border-radius: 0.45rem;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
}
  
.button:before {
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#ccc, #fff);
  content: '';    
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity 0.45s;
}

.button:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<span class='button'>hello</span> i am some text and then <span class='button'>i wrap around the edges</span> and go all the way around
```

Wondering if there is any way to get this working without using JS.

Comment: The overlay is intended? or you want the gradient to remain behind the text?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a similar effect by using a gradient with larger than the display area height, and animating it's position:

```css
.button {
  background-size: 100% 150%;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff 0, #ccc 50%, #fff 100%);
  border-radius: 0.45rem;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-position 0.45s;
}

.button:hover {
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class='button'>hello</span> i am some text and then <span class='button'>i wrap around the edges</span> and go all the way around
```